# Cakephp 3.7 hasOne field data not save

Tags: cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

In cakephp 3.7. Inside our add function . This data save only users table.Profile name field data is not save.

```
$data = [
    'id' => 1,
    'email' => 'cakephp',
    'profile' => [
        'name' => 'cakephp'
    ]
];
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$user = $users->newEntity($data, [
    'associated' => ['Profiles']
]);
$users->save($user);
```

**UsersTable.php**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('users');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasOne('Profiles');
}
```

Can anybody help me. Why profile field data is not save in profiles table

Comment: What says ```debug($user);``` ?

Comment: Please share your associations

Comment: UsersTable.php    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('users');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

       $this->hasOne('Profiles'); 
  
    }

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, it's highly unreadable - thanks!

Comment: @Salines question is still a useful one to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you must modify your Entity too for render accessible the field.

```
protected $_accessible = [
     ...
    'profiles' => true, //if has many
    'profile' => true, //if has one
];
```

Don't forget also to clear the cache if necessary